# Maintain selected dropdown values across multiple pages in php

Tags: php, sql

I have a "page" that is included for the the tabs (home/contact/details) pages etc.
This " included page" has a 3 dropdowns. I am able to store the selected dropdown value and display it in the dropdown box itself.
What i want is the selected dropdown value should be displayed in other pages dropdown also.
In short i want the selected dropdown values to be consistent across all the pages.
I am thinking of using sessions , but not sure how could i use it .

Comment: is there database involved?

Comment: Consistent across the three tabs? Or pages that come afterwards?

Comment: @tonoslfx :Yes database is involved. Values in dropdown are from DB.  Yes want it Consistent across the three tabs( the tabs code are written in 3 different pages itself).

Comment: Are you navigating the pages by simply clicking each tab or is there some sort of button used to progress to each tab?

Comment: I am navigating  by simply clicking on each tab.

Comment: I think this can only be done with javascript and sessions are irrelevant in this situation because you are not changing the overall page.  See my answer below on how to do this using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to store the value when it's changed, and then on every page you'd need to do this:

```
<?php
session_start();
...
echo $_SESSION['dropdown1'];
?>
```

But maybe you'd better use Javascript and store the values in a cookie because that might be easier than updating a SESSION variable when a Javascript event happens (you'd have to do this with AJAX). Does this involve a database or is it just settings such as language or theme?

Comment: I have tried the above code. I have added in all the 3 tabs page code. But the problem is its session value displayed for one tab. When i go to the next tab , no value is displayed

Comment: Yes, the problem is that if the user clicks on a link that is not a submit button you can't save the values with PHP. Hence my suggestion with cookies. Could you please explain what you want to do?

Comment: What i want is depending on selected value from dropdown i want to filter the data and accordingly display. So instead of adding the same dropdown code on each page, i have written code in one page and have included it in the pages across all the 3 tabs.

Comment: Well, you could either store the dropdown values in a cookie with Javascript and have your include file read them in PHP when the page changes. Or you could use PHP sessions but you'd need to setup an AJAX mechanism to store the values in a PHP variable every time they're changed. Either way you need Javascript.

Comment: Since the common page has the dropdown code . i am able to maintain those selected dropdown values on that page. this common page which is included (that is common) across all the tabs. So when i navigate is it that the selected dropdown values vanish from dropdown as the new page loads?

Comment: Yes it's normal since you don't store it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

First Page posted to a php script

```
<form method="POST" action="anotherpage.php> //This is the first page which is
                                             //HTML page
<select name="selected"> 
<option value="Foo">Foo</option>
<option value="Bar">Bar</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Second Page :anotherpage.php

```
<?php
$value=$_POST["selected"];
session_start();
$_SESSION["value"]=$value; // The value is stored in session , it can be used in
                           // subsequent pages
?>
```

Subsequent pages

```
session_start(); //we just have to session_start() then we can use $_SESSION["value"]
echo<<<FOO
    <select>
   <option value="$_SESSION["value"]">$_SESSION["value"]</option>
   <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
    </select>
 FOO;
```

Comment: <form method="POST" action=""> //This is the first page which is
                                             //HTML page
<select name="selected"> 
<option>Foo</option>
<option>Bar</option>       
</select> </form> . This is the common included page in my case for all the tabs. I have no action specified for it. So this code is going to be common for all tabs.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I have rewritten my answer to solve the solution, see comments below for explanation.

Since you are using separate files to display each page and not using ajax, sessions seems to be the best option afterall.  Unfortunately you will still need to set those session variables whenever the option changes.

I have decided not to use cookies for this solution as more people will have cookies turned off than those who turn off javascript.

You can either decide to set the session variables when the page changes, or every time that the select box changes values.  I would suggest doing the former as it would allow for less load on your server (marginally speaking -- you *always* want to look for ways to save overhead).  So to do this in jQuery, you would need a secondary script that can accept a value and then place it into the session variables.

In each of your pages, you would first need to start a session (or join the one that exists already):

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

you would need jQuery that would call this secondary script when the user clicks on one of the tabs and pass the script the data from the dropdown:

**Somewhere on Each Page**

```
$('#tab').click( function() {
    var ddvalue = $("#dropDown").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'secondaryScript.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'value' : ddvalue
        }.
        success: function() {
            //redirect to page that was clicked
            location.href = 'nextpage.php';
        }
    });
});
```

Now, within `secondaryScript.php` you can add the value to the session variables:

**secondaryScript.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['dropDownValue'] = $_POST['value'];
?>
```

Now, within each page, you can reference this value:

```
...
echo $_SESSION['dropDownValue'];
...
```

Of course with select fields, you would need to check your options against this value and add a `selected` attribute to the one that matches.  I can help you with this too if you do not know how.

Comment: I am not using AJAX to load the seperate page. Have given < a href = "page.php"> on each page. Hence the naivgation is occuring. I am trying to understand and implement the solution u gave. I have not used AJAX before...

Comment: Are you using an iframe to display each page?

Comment: No . I have just used plain HTML and php.

Comment: Ahh, I understand now.  I apologize, I should not ASS-U-ME anything and really clarify before answering.  I will rewrite my answer for this specific case.